# Printing SVG from browser

Tags: printing, svg

We are using SVG in our web app and we need to allow users to print SVG images from the browser. We'd like to support Safari and FF. We recently ran into a couple of problems printing from browsers

1. On FF 3.0, we get a gray background color for the SVG area (we are using  for embedding SVG). This does not happen with Safari or FF 3.5.
2. On FF 3.0, we cannot print an HTML with an embedded SVG (using ). But we can save to PDF and print the PDF. The PDF will include the gray backgroud color, but it will at least print.

Have others ran into this problem? Are there any workarounds? I suppose we could always just say we support FF 3.5, but I'd like to leave that as a last resort.

Thanks.

Comment: Not all browsers support SVG. Have you considered converting the images to PNGs or GIFs?

Comment: We are strictly speaking of FF and Safari, both have decent SVG support. This is just a question about printing. We use SVG over PNG and GIFs for many different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grey background colour problem should be this known [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=407305) which appears as resolved at the beginning of august. I can't see it yet in the release notes of current FF3 version 3.0.13 - so you probably have to wait until the next release!